# Sort users by a specific order

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I want to sort users so i have this:

```
 SELECT TOP(@UnitUsers) * FROM users ORDER BY unit_followers DESC
```

And i get: (user_id, username, unit_followers)

```
1 Test  123
2 Admin 89
3 Ola   79
4 Pat   67
5 Twe   54
6 Dry   42
```

But now, i add a new table, *promote* with 2 columns, *user_id* and *sort_order*. In this table a want to set the sort order of specific users. 
This table only contains one user,  user_id = 5 and sort_order = 2. (Can contains more than one user)

How can i get this: (user_id, username, unit_followers)

```
1 Test  123
5 Twe   54
2 Admin 89
3 Ola   79
4 Pat   67    
6 Dry   42
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this custom sort

```
SELECT user_id,
       username,
       unit_followers
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER (ORDER BY unit_followers DESC ) rn,
               a.*,
               b.sort_order
        FROM   users a
               LEFT JOIN promote b
                      ON a.user_id = b.user_id) a
ORDER  BY Isnull(sort_order - 1, rn),rn
```